# Drupal 7 Feeds Module

Tags: 7, feeds

I want to import about 50,000 users using the feeds module. Does anyone know if I need to break that file into smaller rows, say 5,000 records at a time? Is it better to bring the site locally and run the module or can I do this without problem on the server? The reason I ask is because I'm not sure if I will run into memory or execution time limits.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you will have to break the file into smaller pieces. The feeds module supports batch processing for large files.